# On a MAC files placed on a server are greyed out

Tags: macos, file

When our designer places a file on our company server the file is sometimes greyed out and I can't do anything with it. He hasn't changed permissions or anything. Simply updated a psd file and placed on our server so I can pull it down. This doesn't happen all the time.

I've tried reconnecting the server and restarting my machine and it doesn't fix the issue. He ends up having to use a sharing service to get it to me. Eventually it seems like it works but we can't figure out why it doesn't work like normal... sometimes.

----- UPDATE -----

When I try to open the file I get "Item “XXXX.psd” is used by OS X and can’t be opened."

Comment: is the server fast enough??, when you compare it with the earlier speed!
has there been any speed variation?

Comment: Haven't really timed it. Do you think it's just being slow with the upload?

Comment: Could be!
Sometimes too slow servers may cause problems like this!

Comment: When I try to open the file i get `"Item “XXXX.psd” is used by OS X and can’t be opened."`

Comment: Well,I have no idea about that!

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: I created a directory in the same folder as the file... and that fixed the issue. I have no idea why.

Comment: YET ANOTHER EXAMPLE!
Miracles happen.
;)